# DT with Shiny : prevent table output to reload to first page after edit

Tags: r, shiny, dt

The code proposed in https://stackoverflow.com/a/57396067/8648160

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    DTOutput('x1'),
    verbatimTextOutput("print")
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {

    dat <- reactiveVal(cbind(iris, Date = Sys.time() + seq_len(nrow(iris))))

    output$x1 = renderDT(isolate(dat()), selection = 'none', editable = TRUE)

    proxy = dataTableProxy('x1')

    observeEvent(input$x1_cell_edit, {
      info = input$x1_cell_edit
      dat(editData(dat(), info, proxy, resetPaging = FALSE))
    })

    output$print <- renderPrint({
      dat()
    })
  }
)
```

does not work when I upload a file.

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    fileInput("file", label = "Upload data", accept = ".csv"),
    DTOutput('x1'),
    verbatimTextOutput("print")
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {

    dat <- reactiveVal()

    observeEvent(input$file, {
              req(input$file)
              table <- read.csv(input$file$datapath)
              dat(table)
              })

    output$x1 = renderDT(isolate(dat()), selection = 'none', editable = TRUE)

    proxy = dataTableProxy('x1')

    observeEvent(input$x1_cell_edit, {
      info = input$x1_cell_edit
      dat(editData(dat(), info, proxy, resetPaging = FALSE))
    })

    output$print <- renderPrint({
      dat()
    })
  }
)
```

It seems than the problem comes from isolate(...) because the data is updated inside the observeEvent function.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Using a `req` should do the trick:

```
output$x1 <- renderDT({
  req(dat())
  datatable(
    isolate(dat()), selection = 'none', editable = TRUE
  )
})
```